# Obtaining distance from centroid to a boundary in R

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial, shapefile, r-sf

I'm still new to `R`, `raster` and `sf` and I'm having some trouble getting a distance between a point and a polygon for every time period.

I have a sf object with MULTIPOLYGONS that refers to floods (1800s-) and I have another sf object, with information on local authorities for each year (1990-2019). What I want to do is to get - for each year - the distance between the floods that entered the local authority's boundaries and its centroid.

dput of the flood object:

```
dput(rec_simp[0:15,])

    structure(list(rec_out_id = c(5850L, 387L, 388L, 432L, 433L, 
434L, 13895L, 485L, 494L, 486L, 487L, 488L, 489L, 490L, 493L), 
    rec_grp_id = c(1529L, 2995L, 2995L, 2837L, 2837L, 2837L, 
    1528L, 2832L, 2838L, 2832L, 2832L, 2831L, 2831L, 2211L, 2838L
    ), name = c("1991 Flood Event", "June 2007 Event", "June 2007 Event", 
    "20th July 2007 River Teme (Upper)", "20th July 2007 River Teme (Upper)", 
    "20th July 2007 River Teme (Upper)", "Derwent March 1999 Event", 
    "Hatherley Brook 014 (July 07)", "River Chelt 020 (July 07)", 
    "Hatherley Brook 010 (July 07)", "Hatherley Brook 013 (July 07)", 
    "River Twyver 015 (July 07)", "River Twyver 012 (July 07)", 
    "06OctoberAutumn1993", "River Chelt 001 (July 07)"), start_date = c("1991/02/21 00:00:00", 
    "2007/06/25 00:00:00", "2007/06/25 00:00:00", "2007/07/21 00:00:00", 
    "2007/07/21 00:00:00", "2007/07/21 00:00:00", "1999/03/02 00:00:00", 
    "2007/07/20 00:00:00", "2007/07/20 00:00:00", "2007/07/20 00:00:00", 
    "2007/07/20 00:00:00", "2007/07/20 00:00:00", "2007/07/20 00:00:00", 
    "1993/01/01 00:00:00", "2007/07/20 00:00:00"), end_date = structure(c(7727, 
    13692, 13692, 13728, 13728, 13728, 10666, 13715, 13715, 13715, 
    13715, 13715, 13715, 8746, 13715), class = "Date"), flood_src = c("unknown", 
    "ordinary watercourse", "ordinary watercourse", "main river", 
    "main river", "main river", "unknown", "main river", "main river", 
    "main river", "main river", "main river", "main river", "main river", 
    "main river"), flood_caus = c("overtopping of defences", 
    "channel capacity exceeded (no raised defences)", "channel capacity exceeded (no raised defences)", 
    "other", "other", "other", "overtopping of defences", "channel capacity exceeded (no raised defences)", 
    "channel capacity exceeded (no raised defences)", "channel capacity exceeded (no raised defences)", 
    "channel capacity exceeded (no raised defences)", "channel capacity exceeded (no raised defences)", 
    "channel capacity exceeded (no raised defences)", "channel capacity exceeded (no raised defences)", 
    "channel capacity exceeded (no raised defences)"), fm_status = c("considered and accepted", 
    "considered and accepted", "considered and accepted", "considered and accepted", 
    "considered and accepted", "considered and accepted", "considered and accepted", 
    "considered and accepted", "considered and accepted", "considered and accepted", 
    "considered and accepted", "considered and accepted", "considered and accepted", 
    "considered and accepted", "considered and accepted"), hfm_status = c("considered and accepted", 
    "considered and accepted", "considered and accepted", "considered and accepted", 
    "considered and accepted", "considered and accepted", "considered and accepted", 
    "considered and accepted", "considered and accepted", "considered and accepted", 
    "considered and accepted", "considered and accepted", "considered and accepted", 
    "considered and accepted", "considered and accepted"), data_src = c("Survey", 
    "Survey", "Survey", "Survey", "Survey", "Survey", "Survey", 
    "Survey", "Survey", "Survey", "Survey", "Survey", "Survey", 
    "Survey", "Survey"), fluvial_f = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), coastal_f = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), tidal_f = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    data_prov = c("Environment Agency", "Consultants", "Consultants", 
    "Consultants", "Consultants", "Consultants", "Consultants", 
    "Consultants", "Consultants", "Consultants", "Consultants", 
    "Consultants", "Consultants", "Consultants", "Consultants"
    ), data_qual = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), Shape_Length = c(20760.0862653932, 5252.55695170499, 1351.19839926208, 
    3035.78479345996, 292.111553478117, 13065.1591983069, 33868.8400127573, 
    1965.8116220814, 182.660675692031, 608.064648572066, 5726.6767189647, 
    293.667874827532, 627.095371022178, 18794.9886947699, 1353.73265052405
    ), Shape_Area = c(1237802.4776605, 103779.389935562, 55291.5354929778, 
    69156.0770502891, 1965.0632499598, 1466803.0281043, 1416900.42985681, 
    25080.6327434951, 1146.83835103637, 4983.13520000008, 197481.329154195, 
    1969.34710001101, 10711.6358285996, 408274.532087206, 33454.8197105237
    ), geometry = structure(list(structure(list(list(structure(c(4714322.40975255, 
    4716145.71145385, 4716141.55143781, 4717427.56364775, 4716324.5947451, 
    4716461.10167658, 4714322.40975255, 9174996.69745875, 9175917.62285533, 
    9177849.85669808, 9177498.59162881, 9177479.8209956, 9175477.50291387, 
    9174996.69745875), .Dim = c(7L, 2L))), list(structure(c(4716802.0864433, 
    4717252.6371426, 4717597.72146915, 4716802.0864433, 9175230.79164326, 
    9176006.03207018, 9174535.15945656, 9175230.79164326), .Dim = c(4L, 
    2L)))), class = c("XY", "MULTIPOLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(), class = c("XY", 
    "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
    "sfg")), structure(list(), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg"
    )), structure(list(), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), 
        structure(list(structure(c(4916430.99622511, 4915832.129385, 
        4917260.9564723, 4916430.99622511, 9014504.98522568, 
        9016188.32618782, 9019526.22287062, 9014504.98522568), .Dim = c(4L, 
        2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
            list(structure(c(4699944.80708654, 4700006.75806449, 
            4699865.60722585, 4699382.14438072, 4700401.29451328, 
            4701517.9455769, 4702006.65011483, 4701684.1262684, 
            4700509.45768516, 4701081.27791338, 4699944.80708654, 
            9218585.4957194, 9218525.7511143, 9218676.65160039, 
            9219233.06595353, 9218437.62138694, 9220254.68749718, 
            9217855.92841653, 9219406.25470806, 9218177.22178006, 
            9217277.30001825, 9218585.4957194), .Dim = c(11L, 
            2L))), list(structure(c(4699089.36718683, 4696893.93971212, 
            4698990.84856102, 4699089.36718683, 9219410.40506698, 
            9218517.3317958, 9219505.39988582, 9219410.40506698
            ), .Dim = c(4L, 2L)))), class = c("XY", "MULTIPOLYGON", 
        "sfg")), structure(list(), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
        "sfg")), structure(list(), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
        "sfg")), structure(list(), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
        "sfg")), structure(list(), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
        "sfg")), structure(list(), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
        "sfg")), structure(list(), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
        "sfg")), structure(list(), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
        "sfg")), structure(list(), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
        "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_GEOMETRY", "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 4696893.93971212, 
    ymin = 9014504.98522568, xmax = 4917260.9564723, ymax = 9220254.68749718
    ), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(input = "EPSG:32617", 
        wkt = "PROJCRS[\"WGS 84 / UTM zone 17N\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n        DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",4326]],\n    CONVERSION[\"UTM zone 17N\",\n        METHOD[\"Transverse Mercator\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9807]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of natural origin\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8801]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of natural origin\",-81,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8802]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Scale factor at natural origin\",0.9996,\n            SCALEUNIT[\"unity\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8805]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False easting\",500000,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8806]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False northing\",0,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8807]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"(E)\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        AXIS[\"(N)\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"unknown\"],\n        AREA[\"World - N hemisphere - 84°W to 78°W - by country\"],\n        BBOX[0,-84,84,-78]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",32617]]"), class = "crs"), classes = c("MULTIPOLYGON", 
    "POLYGON", "POLYGON", "POLYGON", "POLYGON", "POLYGON", "MULTIPOLYGON", 
    "POLYGON", "POLYGON", "POLYGON", "POLYGON", "POLYGON", "POLYGON", 
    "POLYGON", "POLYGON"), n_empty = 12L), start_date2 = structure(c(7721, 
    13689, 13689, 13715, 13715, 13715, 10652, 13714, 13714, 13714, 
    13714, 13714, 13714, 8401, 13714), class = "Date"), year = c(1991, 
    2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 1999, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 
    2008, 2008, 1993, 2008)), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(rec_out_id = NA_integer_, 
rec_grp_id = NA_integer_, name = NA_integer_, start_date = NA_integer_, 
end_date = NA_integer_, flood_src = NA_integer_, flood_caus = NA_integer_, 
fm_status = NA_integer_, hfm_status = NA_integer_, data_src = NA_integer_, 
fluvial_f = NA_integer_, coastal_f = NA_integer_, tidal_f = NA_integer_, 
data_prov = NA_integer_, data_qual = NA_integer_, Shape_Length = NA_integer_, 
Shape_Area = NA_integer_, start_date2 = NA_integer_, year = NA_integer_
), .Label = c("constant", "aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"), row.names = c(NA, 
15L), class = c("sf", "data.frame"))
```

dput of the local authority object:

```
dput(el9018[0:15,])
      structure(list(name = c("Hartlepool", "Hartlepool", "Hartlepool", 
"Hartlepool", "Hartlepool", "Hartlepool", "Hartlepool", "Hartlepool", 
"Hartlepool", "Hartlepool", "Hartlepool", "Hartlepool", "Hartlepool", 
"Hartlepool", "Hartlepool"), year = c(1996, 2008, 2006, 1990, 
2004, 1991, 1995, 2000, 1994, 2003, 1999, 2002, 1993, 1998, 2007
), st_areasha = c(93865248.283153, 93865248.283153, 93865248.283153, 
93865248.283153, 93865248.283153, 93865248.283153, 93865248.283153, 
93865248.283153, 93865248.283153, 93865248.283153, 93865248.283153, 
93865248.283153, 93865248.283153, 93865248.283153, 93865248.283153
), st_lengths = c(71094.4383027322, 71094.4383027322, 71094.4383027322, 
71094.4383027322, 71094.4383027322, 71094.4383027322, 71094.4383027322, 
71094.4383027322, 71094.4383027322, 71094.4383027322, 71094.4383027322, 
71094.4383027322, 71094.4383027322, 71094.4383027322, 71094.4383027322
), geometry = list(structure(list(structure(c(4620048.87342784, 
4625136.14033251, 4626169.97135356, 4624903.68499877, 4625666.98306727, 
4627236.26049621, 4630383.60094198, 4632181.9934407, 4634222.13636813, 
4633733.53415866, 4634792.40551378, 4632805.240467, 4633813.29962425, 
4632481.55986368, 4629910.70167173, 4631429.43959516, 4628885.5811266, 
4628828.22764404, 4627103.76491929, 4624790.90448235, 4623373.10700597, 
4623774.92804902, 4620554.19293119, 4620048.87342784, 9196890.6003961, 
9203047.88855518, 9203113.63269664, 9201599.80199553, 9202139.15172575, 
9200864.14932645, 9201479.63576469, 9203092.42994029, 9202073.30466573, 
9200275.62185513, 9198288.71461306, 9196674.89026299, 9194785.61668234, 
9191674.23504443, 9190853.39755471, 9189011.54061077, 9185750.32340507, 
9189094.46102474, 9188949.81426043, 9190824.07050973, 9190050.68152116, 
9191979.44980661, 9193807.72767383, 9196890.6003961), .Dim = c(24L, 
2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(4620048.87342784, 
4625136.14033251, 4626169.97135356, 4624903.68499877, 4625666.98306727, 
4627236.26049621, 4630383.60094198, 4632181.9934407, 4634222.13636813, 
4633733.53415866, 4634792.40551378, 4632805.240467, 4633813.29962425, 
4632481.55986368, 4629910.70167173, 4631429.43959516, 4628885.5811266, 
4628828.22764404, 4627103.76491929, 4624790.90448235, 4623373.10700597, 
4623774.92804902, 4620554.19293119, 4620048.87342784, 9196890.6003961, 
9203047.88855518, 9203113.63269664, 9201599.80199553, 9202139.15172575, 
9200864.14932645, 9201479.63576469, 9203092.42994029, 9202073.30466573, 
9200275.62185513, 9198288.71461306, 9196674.89026299, 9194785.61668234, 
9191674.23504443, 9190853.39755471, 9189011.54061077, 9185750.32340507, 
9189094.46102474, 9188949.81426043, 9190824.07050973, 9190050.68152116, 
9191979.44980661, 9193807.72767383, 9196890.6003961), .Dim = c(24L, 
2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(4620048.87342784, 
4625136.14033251, 4626169.97135356, 4624903.68499877, 4625666.98306727, 
4627236.26049621, 4630383.60094198, 4632181.9934407, 4634222.13636813, 
4633733.53415866, 4634792.40551378, 4632805.240467, 4633813.29962425, 
4632481.55986368, 4629910.70167173, 4631429.43959516, 4628885.5811266, 
4628828.22764404, 4627103.76491929, 4624790.90448235, 4623373.10700597, 
4623774.92804902, 4620554.19293119, 4620048.87342784, 9196890.6003961, 
9203047.88855518, 9203113.63269664, 9201599.80199553, 9202139.15172575, 
9200864.14932645, 9201479.63576469, 9203092.42994029, 9202073.30466573, 
9200275.62185513, 9198288.71461306, 9196674.89026299, 9194785.61668234, 
9191674.23504443, 9190853.39755471, 9189011.54061077, 9185750.32340507, 
9189094.46102474, 9188949.81426043, 9190824.07050973, 9190050.68152116, 
9191979.44980661, 9193807.72767383, 9196890.6003961), .Dim = c(24L, 
2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(4620048.87342784, 
4625136.14033251, 4626169.97135356, 4624903.68499877, 4625666.98306727, 
4627236.26049621, 4630383.60094198, 4632181.9934407, 4634222.13636813, 
4633733.53415866, 4634792.40551378, 4632805.240467, 4633813.29962425, 
4632481.55986368, 4629910.70167173, 4631429.43959516, 4628885.5811266, 
4628828.22764404, 4627103.76491929, 4624790.90448235, 4623373.10700597, 
4623774.92804902, 4620554.19293119, 4620048.87342784, 9196890.6003961, 
9203047.88855518, 9203113.63269664, 9201599.80199553, 9202139.15172575, 
9200864.14932645, 9201479.63576469, 9203092.42994029, 9202073.30466573, 
9200275.62185513, 9198288.71461306, 9196674.89026299, 9194785.61668234, 
9191674.23504443, 9190853.39755471, 9189011.54061077, 9185750.32340507, 
9189094.46102474, 9188949.81426043, 9190824.07050973, 9190050.68152116, 
9191979.44980661, 9193807.72767383, 9196890.6003961), .Dim = c(24L, 
2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(4620048.87342784, 
4625136.14033251, 4626169.97135356, 4624903.68499877, 4625666.98306727, 
4627236.26049621, 4630383.60094198, 4632181.9934407, 4634222.13636813, 
4633733.53415866, 4634792.40551378, 4632805.240467, 4633813.29962425, 
4632481.55986368, 4629910.70167173, 4631429.43959516, 4628885.5811266, 
4628828.22764404, 4627103.76491929, 4624790.90448235, 4623373.10700597, 
4623774.92804902, 4620554.19293119, 4620048.87342784, 9196890.6003961, 
9203047.88855518, 9203113.63269664, 9201599.80199553, 9202139.15172575, 
9200864.14932645, 9201479.63576469, 9203092.42994029, 9202073.30466573, 
9200275.62185513, 9198288.71461306, 9196674.89026299, 9194785.61668234, 
9191674.23504443, 9190853.39755471, 9189011.54061077, 9185750.32340507, 
9189094.46102474, 9188949.81426043, 9190824.07050973, 9190050.68152116, 
9191979.44980661, 9193807.72767383, 9196890.6003961), .Dim = c(24L, 
2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(4620048.87342784, 
4625136.14033251, 4626169.97135356, 4624903.68499877, 4625666.98306727, 
4627236.26049621, 4630383.60094198, 4632181.9934407, 4634222.13636813, 
4633733.53415866, 4634792.40551378, 4632805.240467, 4633813.29962425, 
4632481.55986368, 4629910.70167173, 4631429.43959516, 4628885.5811266, 
4628828.22764404, 4627103.76491929, 4624790.90448235, 4623373.10700597, 
4623774.92804902, 4620554.19293119, 4620048.87342784, 9196890.6003961, 
9203047.88855518, 9203113.63269664, 9201599.80199553, 9202139.15172575, 
9200864.14932645, 9201479.63576469, 9203092.42994029, 9202073.30466573, 
9200275.62185513, 9198288.71461306, 9196674.89026299, 9194785.61668234, 
9191674.23504443, 9190853.39755471, 9189011.54061077, 9185750.32340507, 
9189094.46102474, 9188949.81426043, 9190824.07050973, 9190050.68152116, 
9191979.44980661, 9193807.72767383, 9196890.6003961), .Dim = c(24L, 
2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(4620048.87342784, 
4625136.14033251, 4626169.97135356, 4624903.68499877, 4625666.98306727, 
4627236.26049621, 4630383.60094198, 4632181.9934407, 4634222.13636813, 
4633733.53415866, 4634792.40551378, 4632805.240467, 4633813.29962425, 
4632481.55986368, 4629910.70167173, 4631429.43959516, 4628885.5811266, 
4628828.22764404, 4627103.76491929, 4624790.90448235, 4623373.10700597, 
4623774.92804902, 4620554.19293119, 4620048.87342784, 9196890.6003961, 
9203047.88855518, 9203113.63269664, 9201599.80199553, 9202139.15172575, 
9200864.14932645, 9201479.63576469, 9203092.42994029, 9202073.30466573, 
9200275.62185513, 9198288.71461306, 9196674.89026299, 9194785.61668234, 
9191674.23504443, 9190853.39755471, 9189011.54061077, 9185750.32340507, 
9189094.46102474, 9188949.81426043, 9190824.07050973, 9190050.68152116, 
9191979.44980661, 9193807.72767383, 9196890.6003961), .Dim = c(24L, 
2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(4620048.87342784, 
4625136.14033251, 4626169.97135356, 4624903.68499877, 4625666.98306727, 
4627236.26049621, 4630383.60094198, 4632181.9934407, 4634222.13636813, 
4633733.53415866, 4634792.40551378, 4632805.240467, 4633813.29962425, 
4632481.55986368, 4629910.70167173, 4631429.43959516, 4628885.5811266, 
4628828.22764404, 4627103.76491929, 4624790.90448235, 4623373.10700597, 
4623774.92804902, 4620554.19293119, 4620048.87342784, 9196890.6003961, 
9203047.88855518, 9203113.63269664, 9201599.80199553, 9202139.15172575, 
9200864.14932645, 9201479.63576469, 9203092.42994029, 9202073.30466573, 
9200275.62185513, 9198288.71461306, 9196674.89026299, 9194785.61668234, 
9191674.23504443, 9190853.39755471, 9189011.54061077, 9185750.32340507, 
9189094.46102474, 9188949.81426043, 9190824.07050973, 9190050.68152116, 
9191979.44980661, 9193807.72767383, 9196890.6003961), .Dim = c(24L, 
2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(4620048.87342784, 
4625136.14033251, 4626169.97135356, 4624903.68499877, 4625666.98306727, 
4627236.26049621, 4630383.60094198, 4632181.9934407, 4634222.13636813, 
4633733.53415866, 4634792.40551378, 4632805.240467, 4633813.29962425, 
4632481.55986368, 4629910.70167173, 4631429.43959516, 4628885.5811266, 
4628828.22764404, 4627103.76491929, 4624790.90448235, 4623373.10700597, 
4623774.92804902, 4620554.19293119, 4620048.87342784, 9196890.6003961, 
9203047.88855518, 9203113.63269664, 9201599.80199553, 9202139.15172575, 
9200864.14932645, 9201479.63576469, 9203092.42994029, 9202073.30466573, 
9200275.62185513, 9198288.71461306, 9196674.89026299, 9194785.61668234, 
9191674.23504443, 9190853.39755471, 9189011.54061077, 9185750.32340507, 
9189094.46102474, 9188949.81426043, 9190824.07050973, 9190050.68152116, 
9191979.44980661, 9193807.72767383, 9196890.6003961), .Dim = c(24L, 
2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(4620048.87342784, 
4625136.14033251, 4626169.97135356, 4624903.68499877, 4625666.98306727, 
4627236.26049621, 4630383.60094198, 4632181.9934407, 4634222.13636813, 
4633733.53415866, 4634792.40551378, 4632805.240467, 4633813.29962425, 
4632481.55986368, 4629910.70167173, 4631429.43959516, 4628885.5811266, 
4628828.22764404, 4627103.76491929, 4624790.90448235, 4623373.10700597, 
4623774.92804902, 4620554.19293119, 4620048.87342784, 9196890.6003961, 
9203047.88855518, 9203113.63269664, 9201599.80199553, 9202139.15172575, 
9200864.14932645, 9201479.63576469, 9203092.42994029, 9202073.30466573, 
9200275.62185513, 9198288.71461306, 9196674.89026299, 9194785.61668234, 
9191674.23504443, 9190853.39755471, 9189011.54061077, 9185750.32340507, 
9189094.46102474, 9188949.81426043, 9190824.07050973, 9190050.68152116, 
9191979.44980661, 9193807.72767383, 9196890.6003961), .Dim = c(24L, 
2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(4620048.87342784, 
4625136.14033251, 4626169.97135356, 4624903.68499877, 4625666.98306727, 
4627236.26049621, 4630383.60094198, 4632181.9934407, 4634222.13636813, 
4633733.53415866, 4634792.40551378, 4632805.240467, 4633813.29962425, 
4632481.55986368, 4629910.70167173, 4631429.43959516, 4628885.5811266, 
4628828.22764404, 4627103.76491929, 4624790.90448235, 4623373.10700597, 
4623774.92804902, 4620554.19293119, 4620048.87342784, 9196890.6003961, 
9203047.88855518, 9203113.63269664, 9201599.80199553, 9202139.15172575, 
9200864.14932645, 9201479.63576469, 9203092.42994029, 9202073.30466573, 
9200275.62185513, 9198288.71461306, 9196674.89026299, 9194785.61668234, 
9191674.23504443, 9190853.39755471, 9189011.54061077, 9185750.32340507, 
9189094.46102474, 9188949.81426043, 9190824.07050973, 9190050.68152116, 
9191979.44980661, 9193807.72767383, 9196890.6003961), .Dim = c(24L, 
2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(4620048.87342784, 
4625136.14033251, 4626169.97135356, 4624903.68499877, 4625666.98306727, 
4627236.26049621, 4630383.60094198, 4632181.9934407, 4634222.13636813, 
4633733.53415866, 4634792.40551378, 4632805.240467, 4633813.29962425, 
4632481.55986368, 4629910.70167173, 4631429.43959516, 4628885.5811266, 
4628828.22764404, 4627103.76491929, 4624790.90448235, 4623373.10700597, 
4623774.92804902, 4620554.19293119, 4620048.87342784, 9196890.6003961, 
9203047.88855518, 9203113.63269664, 9201599.80199553, 9202139.15172575, 
9200864.14932645, 9201479.63576469, 9203092.42994029, 9202073.30466573, 
9200275.62185513, 9198288.71461306, 9196674.89026299, 9194785.61668234, 
9191674.23504443, 9190853.39755471, 9189011.54061077, 9185750.32340507, 
9189094.46102474, 9188949.81426043, 9190824.07050973, 9190050.68152116, 
9191979.44980661, 9193807.72767383, 9196890.6003961), .Dim = c(24L, 
2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(4620048.87342784, 
4625136.14033251, 4626169.97135356, 4624903.68499877, 4625666.98306727, 
4627236.26049621, 4630383.60094198, 4632181.9934407, 4634222.13636813, 
4633733.53415866, 4634792.40551378, 4632805.240467, 4633813.29962425, 
4632481.55986368, 4629910.70167173, 4631429.43959516, 4628885.5811266, 
4628828.22764404, 4627103.76491929, 4624790.90448235, 4623373.10700597, 
4623774.92804902, 4620554.19293119, 4620048.87342784, 9196890.6003961, 
9203047.88855518, 9203113.63269664, 9201599.80199553, 9202139.15172575, 
9200864.14932645, 9201479.63576469, 9203092.42994029, 9202073.30466573, 
9200275.62185513, 9198288.71461306, 9196674.89026299, 9194785.61668234, 
9191674.23504443, 9190853.39755471, 9189011.54061077, 9185750.32340507, 
9189094.46102474, 9188949.81426043, 9190824.07050973, 9190050.68152116, 
9191979.44980661, 9193807.72767383, 9196890.6003961), .Dim = c(24L, 
2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(4620048.87342784, 
4625136.14033251, 4626169.97135356, 4624903.68499877, 4625666.98306727, 
4627236.26049621, 4630383.60094198, 4632181.9934407, 4634222.13636813, 
4633733.53415866, 4634792.40551378, 4632805.240467, 4633813.29962425, 
4632481.55986368, 4629910.70167173, 4631429.43959516, 4628885.5811266, 
4628828.22764404, 4627103.76491929, 4624790.90448235, 4623373.10700597, 
4623774.92804902, 4620554.19293119, 4620048.87342784, 9196890.6003961, 
9203047.88855518, 9203113.63269664, 9201599.80199553, 9202139.15172575, 
9200864.14932645, 9201479.63576469, 9203092.42994029, 9202073.30466573, 
9200275.62185513, 9198288.71461306, 9196674.89026299, 9194785.61668234, 
9191674.23504443, 9190853.39755471, 9189011.54061077, 9185750.32340507, 
9189094.46102474, 9188949.81426043, 9190824.07050973, 9190050.68152116, 
9191979.44980661, 9193807.72767383, 9196890.6003961), .Dim = c(24L, 
2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(4620048.87342784, 
4625136.14033251, 4626169.97135356, 4624903.68499877, 4625666.98306727, 
4627236.26049621, 4630383.60094198, 4632181.9934407, 4634222.13636813, 
4633733.53415866, 4634792.40551378, 4632805.240467, 4633813.29962425, 
4632481.55986368, 4629910.70167173, 4631429.43959516, 4628885.5811266, 
4628828.22764404, 4627103.76491929, 4624790.90448235, 4623373.10700597, 
4623774.92804902, 4620554.19293119, 4620048.87342784, 9196890.6003961, 
9203047.88855518, 9203113.63269664, 9201599.80199553, 9202139.15172575, 
9200864.14932645, 9201479.63576469, 9203092.42994029, 9202073.30466573, 
9200275.62185513, 9198288.71461306, 9196674.89026299, 9194785.61668234, 
9191674.23504443, 9190853.39755471, 9189011.54061077, 9185750.32340507, 
9189094.46102474, 9188949.81426043, 9190824.07050973, 9190050.68152116, 
9191979.44980661, 9193807.72767383, 9196890.6003961), .Dim = c(24L, 
2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg"))), centroid = list(structure(c(4627696.7784981, 
9195871.63743641), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(4627696.7784981, 
9195871.63743641), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(4627696.7784981, 
9195871.63743641), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(4627696.7784981, 
9195871.63743641), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(4627696.7784981, 
9195871.63743641), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(4627696.7784981, 
9195871.63743641), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(4627696.7784981, 
9195871.63743641), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(4627696.7784981, 
9195871.63743641), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(4627696.7784981, 
9195871.63743641), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(4627696.7784981, 
9195871.63743641), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(4627696.7784981, 
9195871.63743641), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(4627696.7784981, 
9195871.63743641), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(4627696.7784981, 
9195871.63743641), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(4627696.7784981, 
9195871.63743641), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(4627696.7784981, 
9195871.63743641), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")))), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Names = c("name", 
"year", "st_areasha", "st_lengths", NA), .Label = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"), row.names = c(NA, 
15L), class = c("sf", "data.frame"))
```

I got the local authory's centroid with:

```
 el9018_simp <- el9018 %>% 
  st_transform(32617)
el9018_simp$centroid <- st_centroid(el9018_simp$geometry)
```

Following https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/380671/test-intersections-with-time-indicators-in-r/380749?noredirect=1#comment622792_380749,
I tried this `for` loop:

```
library(rgeos)
for(i in unique(el9018_simp$year)) {
    dat1_sub = rec_simp[rec_simp$year == i, ]
    el9018_sub = st_union(el9018_simp[el9018_simp$year == i, ])
    int = st_intersects(
        el9018_sub, 
        dat1_sub,
        sparse = T #keep all floods per year
    )
    for (j in int) {
      dist = gDistance(el9018_sub$centroid, int[j],byid=TRUE)
      el9018_simp$dist[el9018_simp$year == i] = dist
    }
    
}
```

I tried different iterations of this,but I get errors or all NAs for the distance.
Thanks!

Comment: I get an error when trying to manipulate the resulting sf object from your el9018 dput somehow but couple of questions: 
1. your floods are also polygons. Don't you want to get distance between the floods centroids to the local authorities' centroid? 
2. Lots of missing data in your flood dput, could be the issue? 
3. There's also st_distance from sf library for this which you can try and see if it works better.

Comment: Thanks Deter1! So to your qs:1. No, I wanted distance from centroid to closest flood boundary, 2. Sorry for that. I also cleaned my full df and I'm still unable to do it anyhow, 3. So if I were to use st_distance from centroid to flood boundary, it would calculate the distance to the closest flood boundary, would that be it? Thanks again